# Cold water won't turn off

Tags: plumbing, water

I was attempting to change my shower handles out and now I can't get the cold to turn off or adjust at all. Any insight is greatly appreciated! It's a 3 handle set up

Comment: `I was attempting to change my shower handles` ... this does not describe what you actually did .... it does not even say if you removed the old handles

Comment: Pics or it didn't happen. [Edit](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/244914/edit) your question and use the 'mountains' button to add them.

Answer (score 2):

The three-handle tub and shower handles I'm familiar with in North America have a hot water valve on the left, cold water on the right, and a handle to select tub or shower head in the middle.

[image]

If you have a handle (old or new) on the cold valve on the right, the handle may not be making contact with the valve stem inside. You can remove the handle and turn the valve stem inside carefully with pliers, in the off direction (clockwise, I think) to stop the flow of cold water.

Once your emergency is resolved, you'll have more time to check the fit of the handles and whether they really contact the valve stems in the way they're designed to. You may need different handles that are more compatible with your valves.

*There is not much information in the question at the time of this writing, so the answer may change as more information is given.*